# How to draw sphere from polygons taken dynamically from user

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a sphere by code using number of polygons which may very **dynamically** from **100 to 1000** from  user by up and down keys . And those selected number of polygons must be shown on the screen.
What i have seen on google search is creating triangle manually (not dynamically) like this code but still it couldn't help me, Could some one please give me idea:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <gl/glut.h>

const float PI = 3.14159265358979323846f;

#pragma pack(1)
template <typename TYPE>
class GeometryVector
{

    public:

        GeometryVector(const TYPE x_ = TYPE(), const TYPE y_ = TYPE(), const TYPE z_ = TYPE());

        const TYPE x;
        const TYPE y;
        const TYPE z;

};
#pragma pack()

template <typename TYPE>
GeometryVector<TYPE>::GeometryVector(const TYPE x_, const TYPE y_, const TYPE z_)
    :
    x(x_),
    y(y_),
    z(z_)
{
}

class StackedSphere
{

    public:

        StackedSphere(const float radius = 1.0f, const unsigned int stacks = 8, const unsigned int slices = 16);
        void render() const;

    private:

        std::vector<GeometryVector<float> > geometryData_;
        std::vector<unsigned short> indexData_;

};

StackedSphere::StackedSphere(const float radius, const unsigned int stacks, const unsigned int slices)
{
    for (unsigned int stackNumber = 0; stackNumber <= stacks; ++stackNumber)
    {
        for (unsigned int sliceNumber = 0; sliceNumber < slices; ++sliceNumber)
        {
            float theta = stackNumber * PI / stacks;
            float phi = sliceNumber * 2 * PI / slices;
            float sinTheta = std::sin(theta);
            float sinPhi = std::sin(phi);
            float cosTheta = std::cos(theta);
            float cosPhi = std::cos(phi);
            geometryData_.push_back(GeometryVector<float>(radius * cosPhi * sinTheta, radius * sinPhi * sinTheta, radius * cosTheta));
        }
    }
    for (unsigned int stackNumber = 0; stackNumber < stacks; ++stackNumber)
    {
        for (unsigned int sliceNumber = 0; sliceNumber <= slices; ++sliceNumber)
        {
            indexData_.push_back((stackNumber * slices) + (sliceNumber % slices));
            indexData_.push_back(((stackNumber + 1) * slices) + (sliceNumber % slices));
        }
    }
}

void StackedSphere::render() const
{
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &geometryData_[0]);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, indexData_.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &indexData_[0]);
}

class SpiralSphere
{

    public:

        SpiralSphere(const float radius = 1.0f, const unsigned int loops = 8, const unsigned int segmentsPerLoop = 16);
        void render() const;

    private:

        std::vector<GeometryVector<float> > geometryData_;
        std::vector<unsigned short> indexData_;

};

SpiralSphere::SpiralSphere(const float radius, const unsigned int loops, const unsigned int segmentsPerLoop)
{
    for (unsigned int loopSegmentNumber = 0; loopSegmentNumber < segmentsPerLoop; ++loopSegmentNumber)
    {
        float theta = 0;
        float phi = loopSegmentNumber * 2 * PI / segmentsPerLoop;
        float sinTheta = std::sin(theta);
        float sinPhi = std::sin(phi);
        float cosTheta = std::cos(theta);
        float cosPhi = std::cos(phi);
        geometryData_.push_back(GeometryVector<float>(radius * cosPhi * sinTheta, radius * sinPhi * sinTheta, radius * cosTheta));

    }
    for (unsigned int loopNumber = 0; loopNumber <= loops; ++loopNumber)
    {
        for (unsigned int loopSegmentNumber = 0; loopSegmentNumber < segmentsPerLoop; ++loopSegmentNumber)
        {
            float theta = (loopNumber * PI / loops) + ((PI * loopSegmentNumber) / (segmentsPerLoop * loops));
            if (loopNumber == loops)
            {
                theta = PI;
            }
            float phi = loopSegmentNumber * 2 * PI / segmentsPerLoop;
            float sinTheta = std::sin(theta);
            float sinPhi = std::sin(phi);
            float cosTheta = std::cos(theta);
            float cosPhi = std::cos(phi);
            geometryData_.push_back(GeometryVector<float>(radius * cosPhi * sinTheta, radius * sinPhi * sinTheta, radius * cosTheta));

        }
    }
    for (unsigned int loopSegmentNumber = 0; loopSegmentNumber < segmentsPerLoop; ++loopSegmentNumber)
    {
        indexData_.push_back(loopSegmentNumber);
        indexData_.push_back(segmentsPerLoop + loopSegmentNumber);
    }
    for (unsigned int loopNumber = 0; loopNumber < loops; ++loopNumber)
    {
        for (unsigned int loopSegmentNumber = 0; loopSegmentNumber < segmentsPerLoop; ++loopSegmentNumber)
        {
            indexData_.push_back(((loopNumber + 1) * segmentsPerLoop) + loopSegmentNumber);
            indexData_.push_back(((loopNumber + 2) * segmentsPerLoop) + loopSegmentNumber);
        }
    }
}

void SpiralSphere::render() const
{
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &geometryData_[0]);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, indexData_.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, &indexData_[0]);
}

StackedSphere sphere1(4, 8, 16);
SpiralSphere sphere2(4, 8, 16);
int r = 0;

void reshape(int width, int height){
    if (height == 0)
    {
        height = 1;
    }
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gluPerspective(45.0f, GLfloat(width) / GLfloat(height), 0.1f, 50.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -25);
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(-5, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(r, 0, 1, 0);
        sphere1.render();
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(5, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(r, 0, 1, 0);
        sphere2.render();
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    r++;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutInitWindowSize(512,512);
    glutCreateWindow("Sphere Test");
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT, GL_LINE);
    glPolygonMode(GL_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Could some one please give me idea how to generate the sphere using number of polygons decided dynamically by up and down arrow (from 100 to 1000) ?

How to get take the number of polygon dynamically by up and down array (from range 100-1000) and how to show those polygons on the screen ?

How to write the logic such that the number of taken polygon will make a sphere ?

Comment: I can't understand the difference between "manually" and "dynamically". If you want to change geometry you have to update buffers. You might want to have an algorithm which does job for you on keypress - and this is both "manually" and "dynamically". And do you need really custom amount of tiles or 4^n will be enough? ( i mean 1 - 4 - 16 - 64 - 256 ...). It might be not easy to divide sphere to say 17 or 33 tiles (especially if they are rectangular and equal).

Comment: @mlkn by dynamically i mean, as the application launch, user will have any option where he can select the number of polygons(not necessarily triangle) by arrow keys to be be used to create sphere (he will have an option to select from range, lets say 100 to 50000) . On selection it must create a sphere. How to do that in WebGL ?