# How to create sphere using multiple objects

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have to draw sphere  using multiple squares(i am also allowed to use triangles even, but i found some existing code for help in square, so i used it). I have successfully drawn multiple squares (5000).But i don't have to use any inbuit function to create sphere . My code is below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script class="WebGL">
        var gl;
        function createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader)
        {
            var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(vs, vertexShader);
            gl.compileShader(vs);

            if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
                alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vs));
            //////
            var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(fs, fragmentShader);
            gl.compileShader(fs);

            if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS))
                alert(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fs));
            program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(program, vs);
            gl.attachShader(program, fs);
            gl.linkProgram(program);
            if (!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS))
                alert(gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
            return program;
        }
        function createShaderFromScriptElement(gl , shaderName)
        {
            var Shader = document.getElementById(shaderName).firstChild.nodeValue;
            return Shader;
        }
        function start()
        {
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            gl = canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
            if (!gl) { alert("error while GL load"); }

              var vertexShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "2d-vertex-shader");
              var fragmentShader = createShaderFromScriptElement(gl, "2d-fragment-shader");

              var program = createProgram(gl, vertexShader, fragmentShader);

            gl.useProgram(program);
            var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
            var colorLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");
            var resolutionLocation = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_resolution");

            var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
            gl.uniform2f(resolutionLocation, 200, 200);

            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            for (var ii = 0; ii < 5000; ++ii)
            {
                // Setup a random rectangle
                setRectangle(gl, randomInt(300), randomInt(300), 10, 10);
                // Set a random color.
                gl.uniform4f(colorLocation, Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1);
                // Draw the rectangle.
                gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
            }
            function randomInt(range)
            {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * range);
            }

            // Fills the buffer with the values that define a rectangle.
            function setRectangle(gl, x, y, width, height)
            {
                var x1 = x;
                var x2 = x + width;
                var y1 = y;
                var y2 = y + height;
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
                   x1, y1,
                   x2, y1,
                   x1, y2,
                   x1, y2,
                   x2, y1,
                   x2, y2]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        attribute vec2 a_position;
        uniform vec2 u_resolution;

        void main() {
        // convert the rectangle from pixels to 0.0 to 1.0
        vec2 zeroToOne = a_position / u_resolution;

        // convert from 0->1 to 0->2
        vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;

        // convert from 0->2 to -1->+1 (clipspace)
        vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;

        gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace* vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
        }
    </script>

    <script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        precision mediump float;
        uniform vec4 u_color;

        void main()
        {
        gl_FragColor = u_color;  // green
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="start()">
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="800"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i am asked is to draw sphere using multiple objects which i have no idea how to do.And my try was first to draw the multiple objects (5000 in my case) and then try for drawing sphere using it(i mean using these 5000 squares, my next step is to create sphere).

But i don't know how to proceed further to draw sphere using these squares ?

Which i am not able to understand how to do.  Could some one please help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw sphere from polygons taken dynamically from user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33032474/how-to-draw-sphere-from-polygons-taken-dynamically-from-user)

Comment: @mlkn oK, But do you have idea about how to achieve my target ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of approaches is constructing sphere from rectangular tiles in vertex shader.

Generally, the thing is to cover **[0, 2*M_PI] x [0, M_PI]** region with tiles. Say, you have **N** tiles where **N = m*k**, **m** is amount of tiles in a row and **k** is amount of tiles in column.

You can create **N** unit squares and assign to each of them its unique position in **m * k** matrix. Then pass these positions and width/height of tiles (**2*M_PI / m** and **M_PI / k**) as uniforms to vertex shader (or as attributes).

In vertex shader knowing position of tile and its width/height compute vertice's coords on **[0, 2*M_PI] x [0, M_PI]** (they would be **phi** and **ksi**). And then compute actual vertex position on sphere:

```
coord.x = sin(ksi) * cos(phi);
coord.y = sin(ksi) * sin(phi);
coord.z = cos(ksi);
```

Also note you should set up perspective projection for this.

Choosing **m** and **k** is up to you. I recommend to start with square tiles. Here is the picture of result i got this way:

[image]

Comment: You mean something like getting the intersection points where rows and column intersects and create square/rectangle with those intersection points ?

Comment: And what is MP_I ? please explain a bit more your ansser, clearly, its a bit complicated language

Comment: By M_PI i mean [constant Pi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi). Yes, idea is close to what you say, such things often become more clear as you start to code them.

Comment: yes but the problem would be those the number of objects (square/rectangle) will be decided dynamically, i mean user will run the code in browser, he will have input that i want a sphere by lets say ,100 square, then using those 100 square only (of course multiple of 4 as there are 4 sides ) we need to make sphere only. But  how to do that.

Comment: I can't see the problem. Please show your code with working sphere from tiles and your attempts to change tiles amount with concrete place in which you struggle.

Comment: i have solved the problem myself with same approach.. but thanks for ur suggestions.