# How to apply custom mipmaps on a texture in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Contrary to what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040978/mipmap-a-planet-in-three-js) and on the corresponding three.js example, I'm looking at how to apply actual custom mipmaps, i.e. a different custom image for a different mipmap size, NOT just guide three.js to auto-generate mipmaps.
Is this possible? I can't find any example code at all.

The reason is text. Properly created text is superior to any automatic antialiasing, especially on small sizes, when using a different font for a different size. I don't know if this will end to be a better solution in practice, I'm looking to find out.

Comment: See https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_manualmipmap.html

Comment: @gman I only see a single image loaded on that example, where are the rest?

Comment: I dont know why you msged me but I see different  mips in the plane at the bottom and in the code

Comment: different like "mipmap( 64, '#0f0' )" ?  That's obviously generated from the same initial image, not a different **custom** image provided. EDIT: I meant to msg WestLangley

Comment: That's obviously for the floor pattern, but I don't even know where is the documentation for mipmap( 64, '#0f0')  and there is no comment whatsoever on the example about how that works. Like the vast majority of three.js examples, the information in question is buried in unnecessary complexity, that makes each example a **show-off** rather than a **teaching** example.
Like I wrote above, a custom image means exactly that: a custom image provided, not just squares calculated. I need to provide custom text images, so that example is useless to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an array of `image` with dimensions such as [64 x 64, 32 x 32, 16 x 16, 8 x 8, 4 x 4, 2 x 2, 1 x 1], and assign it to the `mipmaps` property of the texture.

The image being used should always be a square, and its dimension should be the power of 2. Each following image in the array should have the dimension halved, until the dimension 1 x 1 is reached.

For your case, you can write a function `textImage` that can draw the same text at a desired dimension and font. Say `(text, dimension, font) => canvas`, where `canvas` is an `HTMLCanvasElement`. Then you can write

```
texture.mipmaps[0] = textImage('sampleText', 64, 'font0');
texture.mipmaps[1] = textImage('sampleText', 32, 'font1');
...
texture.mipmaps[6] = textImage('sampleText', 1, 'font6');
```

And if you don't want to blend the two mipmaps when sampling (for example, you are using different fonts for different levels), you need to set the `minFilter` to `NearestMipMapNearestFilter` or `LinearMipMapNearestFilter`.

(I haven't figured out how to work with incomplete mipmap chain, so I always provide a full chain which is down to 1 x 1. Also, in my understanding, the `image` I mentioned above don't need to be `HTMLCanvasElement`. It could be any type that WebGLRenderingContext.texImage2D() accepts as its `pixels` parameter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D)