# Working with multiple tile map images, and mapping them onto a THREEJS sphere

Tags: three.js

I am building a viewer in threejs, and mapping the original image file onto the sphere works fine, but it takes a large amount of time to get the file from my image server. I have the images split into smaller files as tiles, and I was wondering if there is a way to map these individual files onto a sphere to reduce the load time.

Comment: You can construct sphere from multiple objects, each with its own texture. Some related info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065204/how-to-create-sphere-using-multiple-objects/33086141#33086141).

Comment: You can also use a [`CanvasTexture`](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-canvas-textures.html) and draw the images into the canvas as they download